# crystal reports - limit records at startup to reduce start/refresh time?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, crystal-reports

I have thousands of records that I grouped via crystals wizard but it takes 10 minutes to refresh the data now. Anyway to limit the data so it doesn't take so long to start/refresh?

Comment: Which version of Crystal are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to restrict the number of rows returned to Crystal by a query against a SQLServer database is to add a Top *n* clause to your select statement - like so:

```
select top 100 * from myTable;
```

You can only do this if you are querying your database using the Add Command feature in Crystal, rather than through the Database Expert.

Answer (score 0):

A simple setting can limit the records!! Here it is, if you're using .Net 1.1 (similar set of options in higher frameworks too!).

**Solution 1:** Right click on the report layout > Reports > **Top N/Sort Group Expert** > Choose Top N in the Dropdown that asks for the type of filtering/ sorting you wish to do > Set the Value of top N (100 for ex.) > Uncheck the option that includes other records. You report will be filtered for **only the top N** records from the Dataset.

**Solution 2:** Using the **Record selection formula** where you limit the No. of records on a particular Report/Sub report.
Right click on the report layout > Reports > Record Selection Formula > Enter the formula as "RecordNumber <= N". That's it. The number of records fetched from the Datasource will be only upto N.

Cheers!